# Strava API 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, strava

I'm trying to develop my first java Spring Boot app that calls Strava API and gets my activities for the given period of time.
I've registered my app on Strava's website and got client_id and client secret. I've generated spring-swagger-codegen-api-client and awtowired the client to the app.

```
@Configuration
public class StravaIntegrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ActivitiesApi stravaApi(){
        return new ActivitiesApi(apiClient());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClient apiClient(){
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();

        OAuth strava_oauth = (OAuth) apiClient.getAuthentication("strava_oauth");
        strava_oauth.setAccessToken("X");
        return new ApiClient();
    }

}
```

I'm sure that I use the valid access_Token, my request with this token works fine in Postman.  But when I try to call the method loggedInAthleteActivities I get 401 Unauthorized: [{"message":"Authorization Error","errors":[{"resource":"Athlete","field":"access_token","code":"invalid"}]}]

I tried to change the scope to activity: read or activity: read_all but nothing is changed.
May be anybody knows how to fix it?

```
@Component
public class Adapter {
    @Autowired
    private  ActivitiesApi activitiesApi;

    public void getActivities(Integer before, Integer after, Integer page, Integer perPage) {
        final List<SummaryActivity> loggedInAthleteActivities = activitiesApi.getLoggedInAthleteActivities(before, after, page, perPage);
        System.out.println("All activities from ___ to ___"+ loggedInAthleteActivities.size());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've found the problem and it had nothing to do with Strava api.  There was a mistake in my  apiClient, I created  new ApiClient after the authentication  process:

```
  @Bean
    public ApiClient apiClient(){
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();

        OAuth strava_oauth = (OAuth) apiClient.getAuthentication("strava_oauth");
        strava_oauth.setAccessToken("X");
        **return new ApiClient();**
    }
```

It should be return apiClient, not return new ApiClient.

Comment: To exclude an implementation error on your side, please try the playground: https://developers.strava.com/playground/#/Activities/getLoggedInAthleteActivities At first you should be authorized your session first (can be done on the upper side of the page).

Comment: @squeezer44 yes, I tried  both the playground and requests through the Postman,  these requests are both ok, I can get my activities from Strava. 
But using the same access token I failed to do it an my app

Comment: Did you find something inside the logger.trace? F.e.: Are you quire sure your Spring Boot app is sending the same Bearer token to Strava?

Comment: @squeezer44 thank  you for your help! I've found the problem!

Comment: Please share your solution in here - I'm quite interested in it. And maybe others too,

Comment: @squeezer44  here it is, I've finished it finally  https://github.com/AnnaPo-hub/activityApp